# Como funciona se o usuário abandonou a pergunta em que oferecia recompensa?

Tags: suporte, recompensa

Semana passada respondi a seguinte [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37300/aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-mobile-usando-emissor-ir-com-delphi-xe5-ou-superior/38663#38663) , onde eu e o AP chegamos a discutir um tópico. Depois de um tempo ele não apareceu mais, passou-se quase 7 dias e nada.

O que acontece se ele não validar a resposta? No caso ele abandonou o tópico.

Comment: É possível que seja uma duplicata da pergunta que tem essa resposta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1471/3117 Ou seja, pelas regras da aplicação automática da recompensa, comemore, pois aparentemente ela vai para você mesmo :)

Comment: Outro detalhe, o ato de o AP marcar a sua pergunta como a melhor não atribui automaticamente a recompensa para você, ele poderia por exemplo, caso existissem duas respostas, marcar uma como correta e dar a recompensa para outra.

Comment: não é uma duplicata mas a resposta é a mesma!
vlw

Answer (score 2):

Nada a fazer.

Uma opção é fazer um pequeno comentário não-invasivo, um ou dois dias antes de terminar a recompensa, mas que provavelmente não será respondido.

Parece estranho, mas acontece com frequência. Por qualquer razão, problemas pessoais, desinteresse, esquecimento, a recompensa não é entregue. Se teve sorte de ter dois votos positivos na resposta, depois que começou a recompensa, o sistema vai dar automaticamente 50% da recompensa a essa resposta. Se não tiver esses votos, nada feito.

Ver [**Quando expiram as gratificações?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties).

Comment: Já participei de várias recompensas que não acreditei "como assim, não vai me recompensar?! a resposta é show! pô??". Lição: *entre nas recompensas por sua própria conta e risco*.

Comment: a recompensa veio integralmente para mim...
mas a questão não é a recompensa em si, me empenhei mesmo para ajudar o cara e ele some, se ele validasse pra mim seria como um obrigado e ficaria contente =D

Comment: Usuário sumir sem dar feedback na ajuda dada é normal. Pra mim o estranho é quando tem feedback ;)